# Get a div offset for one page site

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have used bootstrap fixed navigation.

I have a section like

```
<section id="count" class="count-section">
  // here some code 
</section>
```

I am trying to apply an animation, if user scroll and see on this portion. So here I am trying to make it by measure offset. I have tried below code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $('#count').offset().top;
    console.log(pos);
}
```

After reload the page I got value `1539.5333404541016` after scroll page I always get value `1539.5333251953125`.

How can I measure this position from my top fixed navigation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $('#count').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(pos);
});
```

Take a look at `$(window).height()` and `$(document).scrollTop()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wan apply condition on fixed nav position,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $('.navbar').offset().top;    //bootstrap top fixed nav 
    console.log(pos);
}
```

Then scroll and see when your div focus, what the value is ?  Then you can apply the condition.

Comment: it also working but I think top ans is appropriate. Thank you for your ans.